# Visual Basic 2010 - Progressbar - Set back to 0

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer, basic

I am working on a fake tool (just for fun + to learn some more things) and I have a problem.

After doing progressbar increment, I can't get it down back to 0!

Let's explain some things for you to get it right:

1. It's getting increased by a timer (called Timer_IPAInstaller).
   It's code:

   ```
   Ipainstall.Increment(1)
   If ipainstall.Value = 100 Then
       Timer_IPAInstaller.stop()
       MessageBox.Show("The .ipa file was installed successfully!", "Notification!")
   ```
2. The timer is started by a button (called RedemptionButton2). I will not show its code, because it's just a Timer start code.
3. The progressbar is called Ipainstall (as shown in the code).

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: `ipainstall.Value = 0` ?

Comment: @AlexB. But where to add this? At the end of the timer?

Comment: @AlexB. yeah thx. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Thanks to Alex for help.
The working code is here, if you want this:

```
Ipainstall.Increment(1)
    If ipainstall.Value = 100 Then
        Timer_IPAInstaller.stop()
        MessageBox.Show("The .ipa file was installed successfully!", "Notification!")
        Ipainstall.Value = 0
```